# Typeface.js not rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeface.js

just wodering if anyone has experience with Typeface.js ( http://typeface.neocracy.org ) and fixing issues of the font not being rendered in Internet Explorer ( 6, 7 and 8 ).

The font renders in Firefox and Safari fine, hover nothing is displayed in the Explorers. The font is not installed locally so I know that the script is working.

I am using the typical usage of

```
<div class="typeface-js" style="font-family: Optimer">
    text to change
  </div>
```

I have checked the authors forums and using the font file with all of the characters, I just don't know whats up. Also it is being tested on a server, so it is not my browser restrictions for running the content locally.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com) instead.